Simulate stochastic process under variable draw rates
I am running a little program that will make random draws at a variable rate over time. This program needs to tell me if an event occurred or not.
However, if for some reason the frequency of draws goes up, I do not want the frequency of events to go up with it. I need to adjust the probability of an event based on how much time has passed since last time an event happened, or by the number of draws that have been done, or something.
How can I make this work?
Here's the non functioning code:
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

last_time = time.time()
event_times = []
ones = []
p = 1
count = 0

while count < 10:
    time.sleep(np.random.rand()/100) # Random draw rate
    dt = time.time() - last_time
    dp = 1 - np.exp(-p*dt) # Adjusted probability
    r = np.random.rand()
    if r < dp:
        event_times.append(dt)
        ones.append(1) # Just for  plotting
        last_time = time.time()
        count += 1

plt.figure()
plt.plot(event_times,ones,marker='o')
plt.show()


I believe I solved it myself. The problem was that dt was the time to the last event, but it should be adjusted to the last draw instead. Changing that fixed it.
